# typescript compiler bundle doesn't contain dependencies

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I try to bundle my angular2 application with the typescript compiler with a tsconfig.js like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outFile": "bundle.js"
  }
}
```

It creates a bundle.js but without any angular-depenencies. It only includes my own components and typescript files. Any idea how I can tell the compiler to include the referenced dependencies as well into the bundle?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention *what* exactly you want to bundle; the Angular 2 framework itself, or its type definition files only. I presume the former is correct.

The TypeScript compiler **won't** bundle your app for you, it will just compile TS code to JS.
Perhaps the confusion lies in the `outFile` option, which [is stated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to:

> Concatenate and emit output to single file […]

… but applies only to TS input files in your own application.

In order to include the Angular 2 source files with your application, you'd have to use a *bundler* such as *[webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)*.