# How do I get TypeScript to bundle a 3rd party lib from node_modules?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I would like the TypeScript Compiler to use `node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts` to typecheck my code and also bundle `node_modules/firebase/firebase.js` into some of the files where I import things from firebase. I understand there are [many options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062852/npm-vs-bower-vs-browserify-vs-gulp-vs-grunt-vs-webpack) which will do this for me, but I'd like to keep a minimal dev environment.

I have set `"moduleResolution": "node"` in my `tsconfig.json`, which imports the definitions and type checks my code as I want. I've also added  `"isolatedModules": true` in an attempt to have it bundle the actual code into each of my targets, but the generated code does not bundle firebase.js as I would like. Is there a `"module"` compiler option which will do this for me, or should I be adding something else?

If I absolutely need another tool in my dev process, what is the simplest addition to `tsc` which will bundle each of my JS files + their dependencies into a single js file bundle?

Comment: You should consider narrowing this down to the question in your first sentence. The last two phrases are making a separate question that is not only too vague, but has also been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062852/npm-vs-bower-vs-browserify-vs-gulp-vs-grunt-vs-webpack

Comment: my question is specifically the last one — should I be using `tsc` for bundling? I'll remove the type checking, as that's clearly what `tsc` is designed for. good point, thanks.

Comment: That might also be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40019087/1233251 Although it mentions Node.js modules specifically, it covers why `tsc` is typically not used for bundling.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42788059/1233251

Comment: Thanks, that's a bit of a confusing question, but the answer does answer mine as well. Happy to make this one more clear-cut one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM vs. Bower vs. Browserify vs. Gulp vs. Grunt vs. Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062852/npm-vs-bower-vs-browserify-vs-gulp-vs-grunt-vs-webpack)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a duplicate, since that doesn't ask specifically "how do I use `tsc` for bundling?", which is something not wholly unreasonable for it to do given how many `"module"` options there are.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the exact same question. If the answers in the other question also answer this one, then it's a valid duplicate target.

Comment: Let me clarify: the question does not ask it and the answer does not answer it. More specifically, the answer doesn't mention `tsc` and only mentions TypeScript in a different context.

Comment: That detail is not important because it doesn't matter. You would bundle a TypeScript project with the same technologies as bundling a JavaScript project, while also adding some middleware to transpile each module. Also note that I only chose this particular question as a duplicate because you _linked it in your answer_.

Comment: Yes, it's part of the answer, but it is far from the complete answer. Happy to collaborate with you on getting the perfect answer here, and appreciate the pointers. I really would rather not spend time defending my decision to document this specific problem I've run into.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`tsc` is a compiler, not a bundler. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062852/npm-vs-bower-vs-browserify-vs-gulp-vs-grunt-vs-webpack) expounds on bundling a bit.

While developing in TypeScript, [`gulp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify) + [`gulp-browserify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify) can provide a watcher and bundler.

With `"module": "umd"` in the compiler options, this `gulpfile.js` will do the rest:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/*.ts')
    .pipe(ts.createProject('tsconfig.json')())
    .pipe(browserify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/gen'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['default'], function () {
  gulp.watch('src/*.ts', ['default']);
});
```